# What are the girlfriend quests I need to complete in order to achieve 100% completion?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

I am trying to 100% GTA IV, but I'm currently stuck at 97.50% completion. The only section I haven't completed 100% is girlfriends.

What are the girlfriend quests I need to complete in order to achieve 100% completion?

Comment: Welcome to the site gamer! I've edited your question to make it work better on the site. There wasn't enough to go on in order to answer the original question, so I've made your question more general and narrowed the scope.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a specific answer, but there are several "100% checklist" web pages that might be helpful, such as [this one](http://www.gta4.net/100-percent-completion-checklist/).

I can't see any girlfriend-specific tasks in that list though. This [girlfriend guide](http://au.faqs.ign.com/articles/873/873184p1.html) does have some hints (see section 6):

*Michelle and Kate are met through the game storyline and while dating them don't 
provide any real tangible benefit (Hot Coffee not withstanding) they 
do contribute to a 100% game completion*

***IMPORTANT NOTE*** If you want to get the perfect 100% girlfriend 
 fondness that's needed for the XBOX360 achievement, you need to have 
 Michelle's fondness at 100% before the mission "Snow Storm".

I have no idea if the requirement for the achievement is the same as the one for 100% completion in the game though...